# Does A* algorithm work with negative edge weights?

Tags: algorithm, search

I was trying to figure out why the heuristic used in A* tree search needs to be admissible if A* has to be optimal. By tree search I mean that there is no explored set maintained by the algorithm.

While doing this, I ran into the question: Does A* work for negative edge weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The A* algorithm is basically [Dijkstra’s algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) with heuristics. And Dijkstra’s algorithm does not work with negative edge weights. So A* won’t work with negative edge weights neither.

If you’re looking for an algorithm that works with negative edge weights, take a look at [the Bellman-Ford algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm) (but it doesn’t use heuristics).

Comment: doea A* work with negative edges if there are no negative cycles?

Answer (score 1):

This excellent article regarding Dijkstra's may prove helpful and provides a nice example about negative edges...

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960208.html

Comment: Dijkstra’s algorithm does not work with negative edge weights.

Comment: Thank you for the summary Gumbo.